# Deploy Log4j V2 in a JavaFx project connected to Documentum

Tags: javafx, log4j2, documentum

I am doing a `JavaFx` project connected to Documentum data storage and I am trying to add the logging feature using `Log4jV2` I have already downloaded the file and added the following Jars  in to my libraries file . (`log4j-api-2.6.2.jar , log4j-core-2.6.2.jar`) and successfully imported the followings :

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
```

Then I created a file called config.xml with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info"  additivity="false"/>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
  </Configuration>
```

and placed it in my source file next to my other classes then started to configure it as beloew :

```
public class BGMController implements Initializable {
    static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(BGMController.class.getName());

/////other content of my program /////////////////

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     DOMConfigurator.configure("config.xml");

    //  createCheckbox();
    //  createTable();

        logger.warn(" test Sample warn message");
        logger.error(" test Sample error message");
        logger.fatal(" test  Sample fatal message");
        logger.debug(" test Sample debug message");
        logger.info("  test Sample info message");



    }


}
```

As a result I get all these errors plus my Error , warn , fatal seems to be working fine and not the debug and info  :

Any idea how can I fix this . it has taken me quite a few days and I have no idea where am I doing my mistake :|

```
    0 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Problem locating log4j configuration
    3 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Using default log4j configuration 
    20900 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN application.BGMController  -  test Sample warn message
    20900 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR application.BGMController  -  test Sample error message
    20901 [JavaFX Application Thread] FATAL application.BGMController  -  test  Sample fatal message
```

Comment: Do you ever close your `<Configuration>` tag?

Comment: @MichaelPickett Missed in the question . Thanks for noticing ;)

Comment: Was that the problem or you just missed pasting it in the question?

Comment: @MichaelPickett Just missed it in the question :D

Answer (score 1):

DomConfigurator is for Log4j 1.x so you are never configuring Log4j. The default behavior should be taking place of only logging errors and fatal to STDOUT.

You want to use Configurator is Log4j 2. But since you have declared a static Logger before your initialize method can ever be called Log4j is going to initialize before you have a chance to configure it, so you will probably end up with the default configuration being created first and then your configuration after you call the initialize method.

Comment: hmmm ... So based on my understanding I am using the syntax for log4j V1 to configure the xml file and since i am using the version 2 it faces error and doesnt work out and  my static initialization doesnt find any configurator so it just uses the default one ? Am I right ? :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.

Comment: I see ... which will lead up to the next question and that's how am I supposed to configure the xml in version 2.? XD

Comment: Your XML looks ok except for the doctype. Just remove that. Oh, and because you don't have additivity="false" anything routed to the org.apache.log4j.xml Logger will be logged twice.

Comment: I've updated my xml file as you mentioned (in the question) . Just remains that how should I specify to follow the config.xml ? :)